# How to pass the acquired ID param into a variable - React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using axios to make several http request simultaneously. Like so:
[image]
[image]

Afterwards I create a helper function called renderMoviesTrending() to show the data acquired from the api

As you can see from the screenshot, I am passing the movie id (movieTrending.id) via a onPress to the function onPressPosterTrending. This allows me to pass the data of a single selected movie along to movieDetails.js. (all this works fine)
[image]

The issue that I am facing now is I need to make a new api call where I must place the movieTrending.id in it, to retrieve a new set of data that allows me to play trailers for a chosen movie based of of the movie id.

The new url for that http request for retrieving the data concerning trailers is the following -> https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/**353486**/videos?api_key=2e3b3e231665535756b50c3e216e0467

Where the api data looks like this:
[image]

So when I create a new helper function to make that http request, how to get the movie id from the previous function into the url ?

[image]

**UPDATED Code of my app.js**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/84107c7d295a848fbe1102b6df9ee8f5

I hope you guys understand what I am trying to achieve here. I have googled this but not really found anything. Maybe I am searching on the wrong keywords

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I feel the easiest way is just storing the current movie trending ID in the state as a new variable. That way it will be available for the whole component.

You are actually already storing the current trending movie.

You can just access it with this.state.selectedMovieTrending.

So your url becomes: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{this.state.selectedMovieTrending}/videos?api_key=2e3b3e231665535756b50c3e216e0467

Or 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'  + this.state.selectedMovieTrending + '/videos?api_key=2e3b3e231665535756b50c3e216e0467

Comment: how to do this exactly? this is what I was trying to google for but good not find a code example

Comment: See my edited answer. You can just access the state directly. Is another variable.

Comment: mmm does not seem to work, it not logging and I get warnings -> https://gyazo.com/e192e7fd198cf5569e66ba88786649cc

Comment: Can you log the final URL? I don't see it in the screenshot.

Comment: thats the problem, its not logging for some reason. screenshot -> https://gyazo.com/c313ed6bd8530c10748986283a758f0b

Comment: Ah, my bad. You are actually just launching all the requests at once, when you actually don't have the selected movie yet. I thought you were requesting them one by one. You will need to defer the trending promise until someone actually selected the movie.

Answer (score 0):

use flatlist from react native 
like this

```
 <FlatList
     data={this.props.posts}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item._id}
     renderItem={({item}) =>{
            return(
                  <View >
                   <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SingleMovieScree',{movieid:item.id})} >
                     // Use React navigation to nvaigate to another screen 
                    <Image style={styles.Poster} source={{ uri: `${TMDB_IMG_URL}${(movieTrending.poster_path)}` }} /> 
                   </TouchableHighlight>
                  </View>  
                 )
               }
             }
            />
```

so on another screen you will get movie id parameter like this

```
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.movieid);
```

then use this id to get movie details from request and display in your screen